# Display URL info in a thin Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome

I'm developing a mobile site. For reference, I'm using a Google Chrome window about 320px wide.

I'd like to view the URL without having to widen the window. Yes, there are three extensions showing in my screenshot, but even removing those will not show me enough URL info.

I was thinking of a small info bar I could install as an extension, but that doesn't exist. Maybe there's another way? I'd like it to be a solution that works with all websites, not just a bit of text in the sites I'm making.

[image: Thin Google Chrome window with URL barely visible]

Comment: Will it be okay if solution involves something outside of Chrome (a third party utility)?

Comment: Is there something wrong with right-click | View page info ?

Comment: View page info doesn't show the fulll URL e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/601125/display-url-info-in-a-thin-chrome-window .. as for 3rd party, depends on the solution. I had been looking for a Chrome plugin before, which I consider to be 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), I have created a script which Shows a small overlay having the URL of the currently open Chrome tab.

[image: Showing the Overlay]

```
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode, slow

;Overlay Creation

Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow ; +ToolWindow avoids a taskbar button and an alt-tab menu item.
Gui, Color , F1F1F1
Gui, Font, s12  ; Set a large font size (32-point).
Gui, Add, Text, w1336 vMyText
SetTimer, UpdateOSD, 500
Gosub, UpdateOSD  ; Make the first update immediate rather than waiting for the timer.
Gui, Show, x0 y650 AutoSize NoActivate  ; NoActivate avoids deactivating the currently active window.
return

UpdateOSD:
WinGetText, text, A
FoundPos := RegExMatch(text, "\n(.*)", SubPat)
GuiControl,, MyText, URL: %SubPat1%
return
```

To get it running all you need to do is - Install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), then save above script with `.ahk` extension and run it. (or you can create `exe` from that script for portability)
This script can be modified according to particular needs (font, color, location on screen etc.).

Comment: Bravo. A creative solution. I just started using AutoHotKey again the other day, so to have a script that does what I want and I can hack myself is excellent. Thank you!